# Can't deploy Jersey with HK2 in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, dependency-injection, jersey, jersey-2.0, hk2

I have a working Jersey JAX-RS Application and I just modified it to inject a dependency in one constructor. I tried to deploy it at GlassFish, but then I got this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55446905/weld-001408-unsatisfied-dependencies-for-type-in-glassfish-jersey-2).

So I thought about trying on Tomcat instead, since I think this is a problem with how HK2 and CDI can conflict with each other, but it didn't work on Tomcat either, I am getting this error when I deploy my war file:

> SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.beforeStart Exception fixing docBase for context [/Gradle___com_myproject___webservice_1_0_0_SNAPSHOT_war]
>    java.io.IOException: Unable to create the directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\Gradle___com_myproject___webservice_1_0_0_SNAPSHOT_war]
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ExpandWar.expand(ExpandWar.java:115)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.fixDocBase(ContextConfig.java:615)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.beforeStart(ContextConfig.java:748)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:301)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:395)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:149)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1736)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
>       at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>       at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>       at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:482)
>       at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
>       at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>       at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>       at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
>       at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
>       at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
>       at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1408)
>       at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Here's my `AbstractBinder` implementation for DI:

```
public class UsersDependencyBinder extends AbstractBinder {    
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UsersDependencyBinder.class);

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        try {
            // Acts as a Singleton
            bind(new UsersDAO(new CachedDbConnector()));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            LOG.error("Error registering the DB Driver Manager", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how I inject it:

```
private final UsersDAO dao;

@Inject
public UserResource(UsersDAO dao) {
    this.dao = dao;
}
```

The rest of the code worked fine before and is just a `ping`, it does nothing, I am trying to just get the infrastructure working (servers responds to API calls, databases are up and running and etc.) before getting to code.

I tried to add:

```
implementation ("org.glassfish.jersey.bundles:jaxrs-ri:2.27")
```

But it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple actually, but not well documented.

I have Tomcat running locally on Windows, installed with the Windows installer, it will be inside the `Program File` folder, which has write protection by common users, so IntelliJ IDEA couldn't deploy my `war` file at the `webapps` folder.

There are two ways of fixing this:

1. Change the `webapp` folder permission to allow writes from Users.
2. Change the default `webapp` folder location inside `server.xml` in the Tomcat installation.